# How to figure out which pseudo class is currently being used?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to figure out which pseudo class is being used in my element javascript.

Is there something along the lines of:
`$.('#element').attr('pseudoClass')`

EDIT:
Pseudo classes like - :hover :active :focus

Comment: What pseudo class are you talking about?

Comment: @k.chao.0424 Are you talking about things like `:hover`, `:visited` and the like?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to get all the pseudo-classes an element has, as far as I know.

You could write a function, which would require checking for all the pseudo-classes though, and considering there're many of them, that's a difficult job.

```
function getStates(element){
  var states = [];
  ["active","hover","checked",
   "enabled", "animated", "first", 
   "disabled", "empty", "even",
   "odd","header","hidden",
   "focus","image","input",
   "last-child","last-of-type","last"
   "only-child",...].forEach(function(x){
     if($(element).is(`:${x}`)) states.push(x);
  })
  return states;
}
```

That function would have to be called like `getStates("#element")` and would return the array of states which that `#element` has got.

Complete list of selectors is available [there](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's .is() method like this:

```
$('#element').is('pseudoClass')
```

And just replace pseudoClass with a real pseudoClass such as :hover or :active